# Update string column having array of json strings using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, data-analysis, azure-synapse, analysis

I have a table (lets call it TableX) with two columns

```
id           colX 
123          { "name": "abc", "type": "solid"}, { "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}
456          { "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}
```

colX is of type nvarchar having values comma separated Json strings.
I have got another table (lets call it TableY) having two columns

```
id           colY
123          abc
456          xyz
```

I have to write a sql query to remove the matching values of colY in tableY with the values of property name in ColX

for example for above data , output should be

```
id         Col
123        { "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}
456         NULL
```

row with id - 123 has removed the json entry of name-abc and row with id 456 json entry of name-xyz

Is there any recommended approach to achieve this?

Here is one approach I am thinking .

1. Expand the tableX to multiple rows (separate row for each element in json array)
2. do the left join of TableX to TableY using Id column  and colY with ColX (by checking if ColX contains ColY)
3. group by only on those rows which are not matching .

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8, then `json` type column instead of `nvarchar` would help. This will make sure JSON validity also.  And your first record having value `{ "name": "abc", "type": "solid"}, { "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}` is an invalid JSON. There are 2 comma separated json objects. Ideally, there should be an ARRAY, e.g. `[{ "name": "abc", "type": "solid"}, { "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}]` to make it a valid JSON.  If it is a JSON type column, then MySQL has a lot of JSON functions added to query on those.

Comment: Also, if you go with JSON type column, it would be better to have a uniform format for all the records.  I.e. even if a specific record has a single JSON object, still store everything as an array. e.g. `[{ "name": "xyz", "type": "liquid"}]`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you store the data in this pseudo-JSON format when you really want to add or remove entries as if they are rows in a table? Wouldn't it have been easier to store them as normal rows and columns? Then you could use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Comment: pseudo JSON format was coming from legacy application , but I have the contol over storing it in a valid Json array.  I have shared one possible approach , please let me know your thoughts on that